# Exception starting filter ApplicationInsightsWebFilter

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

I followed below article to set up appinsights to java dynamic web project:

[Quickstart: Get started with Application Insights in a Java web project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started)

However I get the below mentioned error. Error Stack trace:

```
Jan 05, 2017 5:40:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter ApplicationInsightsWebFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image: I have the corresponding jar in build path]

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` Fix it by adding the jar to your classpath

Comment: I have It added in the build path. I get this error in spite of that. applicationinsights-web-10.6.jar has the class.

Comment: I followed this answer in below article and the classnotfound exception got fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787859/classnotfoundexception-even-though-the-jar-containing-the-class-is-properly-pres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a summary, seems that you had resolved the issue which might be caused by not automatically loading the added jar files on Tomcat via Eclipse. The solution is that as below.

1. Move to the `Properties > Deployment Assembly` of the current project, and check whether the dependencies exists there as `Build Path` entries or `Archives`.
2. Select the current project, and click `Project > Clean` at the menu bar, then restart the server.