# Unable to parse String JSON inside post request using jersey and java

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am working on a jersey - java project where I have to get the json data in string format and parse each data separately. I am able to get the response in string using post method. When I try to use JSON lib to parse the string data `class not found exception` is produced. I want the returned string to be split up. Below is my json.

```
{
    "startdate": "11/11/11",
    "enddate": "12/12/12",
    "operation_name": "task1",
    "user_id": "user1",
    "operation_key": ["KKMM-025", "SFF-025", "TTR-022"]
}
```

Resource method

```
@POST
@Path("OpertaionDetails")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response CreateOperations(String incoming_data) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser(); // class not found exceptin i have added  the lib properly its working fine when it is used in main method of java.
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(incoming_data);
    JSONObject  Jstart_date =  (JSONObject) jobj.get("startdate");
       // this data to be paresed

    System.out.print("incomingData"+incoming_data);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.ok(incoming_data).build();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? If yes, what does it say? The error in the comments can also state that the jar isn't in your application's classpath?

Comment: yes , if i added JSONParser  lib to parse JSON data, it say's class not found -org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser , but i have tested this main class it works fine i have imported all the required lib's

Comment: Try doing a project clean in your IDE followed by a project refresh...

Comment: i tried rebuilding my project. still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788866/1004631

Comment: I have tried the above solution it dint work. The problem is that class won't execute only when i make a post request. if i run a normal class i am able to get all the details and work on it properly.